# Apply multiple functions to multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, iterable

```py
a=[2,1,3]
b=[4,2,3]
c=[5,4,6]
....

a=set(sorted(map(lambda x: pow(x,3), a)))
```

How do I apply the same sequence of functions : `set()`, `sorted()` and `pow()` to multiple lists `a`, `b` and `c`... above without repeating `x=set(...` *n* times using `map` and `lambda` (or any other more efficient code)?

I know we can use a loop like my own answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67619295/6210219).

But what if we'd like to abstract this task further, so that a given list of functions `[f1, f2, f3, f4]` can be applied to a large number of lists `a`, `b`, `c` of a similar format? (Can `itertools` be used for the task?)

Comment: Use a loop? `for lst in [a,b,c]: ...`????

Comment: That doesn't make any sense though, because `pow([2,1,3],3)` is a `TypeError`, you can't use `pow` on a list, it requires a number

Comment: ok well, then loop over the lists.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, is further abstraction doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[2,1,3]
b=[4,2,3]
c=[5,4,6]

new=[]
for lst in [a,b,c]:
    new.append(set(sorted(map(lambda x: pow(x,3), lst))))

a,b,c = new
```

As suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga in comments above, a loop can be used.